# How to link to current page with different param in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have the following routes set up (just an example, actual routes aren't this messy):

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/app/fun/:userid/profile" component={Profile} exact/>
    <Route path="/photos/:userid" component={Photos} exact/>
    <Route path="/:userid/contact" component={Contact} exact/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

From **ANY** of the pages above, how can I link to the **SAME** page, but with a different `userid`?

eg:

```
/**
 * Shared component that's rendered by Profile, Photos and Contact
 */
class SharedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const bobId = 423423432;

    return (
      <div>
        <Link to={/* what to put here? */}>
          Redirect to the same page but with Bob's userid
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SharedComponent);
```

*Note: using react router v4*

Comment: Is your question how to link to the same page from the same page but pass different data to itself?

Comment: It's a shared component that's used by all of the pages and I want to render a link in that component that will redirect to the current page (with different data)

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do this. Not sure if it's the best way, but it works:

```
/**
 * Shared component that's rendered by Profile, Photos and Contact
 */
class SharedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { location, match } = this.props;
    const bobId = 423423432;
    const bobUrl = location.pathname.replace(match.params.userid, bobId);

    return (
      <div>
        <Link to={bobUrl}>
          Redirect to the same page but with Bob's userid
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SharedComponent);
```

Essentially, I'm taking the current url (`location.pathname`) and replacing the current userid (`match.params.userid`) with the new id (`bobId`)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `userId` with path props to shared component like below,

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const bobId = 423423432; // Pass bobId with path from parent to child
        return (
            <SharedComponent path={"/stuff1/stuff2/`${bobId}`/profile"} />
        );
    }
}


class SharedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to={this.props.path}>
          Redirect to the same page but with Bob's userid
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SharedComponent);
```

Comment: hmm.. I'd have to generate the correct path and pass it to `SharedComponent` every time I want to use it which is annoying...